# How can this comparator not follow its general contract?

Tags: java, exception, comparator

[Problem fixed, see edit at bottom]

This method, which I've used previously, is now throwing an exception for the reason of not following it's general contract.

```
private Face[] sortByDistance(Face[] faces, final Point3D p) {
    final Comparator<Face> faceComparator = new Comparator<Face>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Face o1, Face o2) {
            return MathUtils.distance(o2.getAveragePoint(), p) - MathUtils.distance(o1.getAveragePoint(), p);
        }
    };
    Arrays.sort(faces, faceComparator); // Exception occurs here.
    return faces;
}
```

I know for certain the Point3D from the arguments is what's causing it to sometimes throw this exception. Only certain points cause this though, and some work fine. Why?

Here are some sample points that did cause an exception:

```
(2.9081598E-6,-38.519745,18.787334)
(-15.432643,38.19713,11.813029)
(-20.884119,28.744518,-23.96541)
(5.961947,16.380322,-39.151947)
(3.7570944,3.6281846,-42.537693)
(-20.747366,9.237327,-36.34492)
(-17.694483,20.355177,-33.30626)
(-5.3533697,30.360487,-29.771076)
(14.785507,34.832466,-20.12021)
```

If it helps, I've only just noticed this after putting it inside an object that extends Thread and runs itself, and constantly loops through a series of methods, one of which calls the above method with the exception. It hasn't done this until now, so if there might be some concurrent reason, I would expect it.

[Edit] The problem was that Point3D "p" in the arguments is a mutable object, and an object on a different thread was making changes to it.

Comment: That usually means you have some problem with transitivity. I recommend stepping the sort by hand and noting the results of each comparison. Is the distance, perhaps, rounded so that sometimes the difference is rounded to zero instead of slightly positive or negative?

Comment: could you give an example of which points do cause problems and which  don't?

Comment: What is `MathUtils.distance` doing? It returns an integer result which might not really reflect the 3D distance of the points.

Comment: If this runs in a thread, are you sure that the `getAveragePoint` method returns the same result each time it is called?

Comment: @Henry you may be right there. I'll check that real quick.

Comment: `getAveragePoint` should be thread safe, at least for the faces being processed over. They are created when the object performing operations on them grabs them. From that point on, those objects only exist for that object, and can't be modified

Comment: Found the answer. The Point3D in argument was being modified by another thread while the above array was being sorted.